# How can i download Linux python version module on Win?

Tags: python, pip

I want to download some python package from Win to Linux.
I run `pip download -r requirements.txt -d wheelhouse` on Win10,
but it will download the win version package  `numpy-1.19.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`
Can i download with linux verson of package on win.

Comment: What do you expect the difference to be?

Comment: What is the point of doing this?

Comment: I suppose one reason may be that you want to build a Linux Docker container on a Windows machine and test such software. Though I would try to use the `any` distribution. In any case, the `--platform` option should do the trick. See answer below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+download+Linux+windows

Comment: @kaya3 Binary wheels contain compiled extensions, different for every platform (processor architecture, OS, Python version, 32/64-bits).

Comment: @CATboardBETA To copy the downloaded wheels to an offline host with a different architecture.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do this. By default, `pip` uses your local architecture so it downloads the windows files. The `pip download` options has a `--platform` option.

You can try: `pip download -r requirements.txt -d wheelhouse_linux --platform manylinux1_x86_64 [--only-binary=:all: or --no-deps]`

The documentation for `pip download` is available [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/) with examples.

Comment: "*I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do this…*" To copy the downloaded wheels to an offline host with a different architecture.

Comment: "*`linux_x86_64`*" Isn't it `manylinux1_x86_64` now?

Comment: I think you're right. I guess those examples are outdated. Re-adjusting answer.

Comment: --platform require `--only-binary=:all: or --no-deps ` , download will failed when the package does not have binary version. Finally, i create the same environment to download package for offline server.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I adjusted my answer. Glad it worked for you.